# dlib module is not found

Tags: python, linux, dlib

I'm running python code which uses the `dlib` module. I'm using arch linux, so I downloaded `dlib` from here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dlib/

Then I try to import the dlib module, but it still doesn't work:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'`

Is there a dependency that I didn't download or am I downloading the wrong module? I can't figure out what the problem is, since I downloaded the official module already.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, all you have to do is to search in your package manager if you are a linux user, and try importing dlib in your python code, if that didn't work, then download dlib from this link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/latest/download
extract the files, and run the setup.py files, it will take a while till it finishes, and that should make it work, you can now run codes using dlib library with no problems.
hope that helps someone :D.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue, but you need to download it to your site-packpages of where your python is there for python-idle or if ur getting a download error in pycharm , I solved the error by downloading dlib from cmd to the venv of my pycharm.project directory command being install dlib--19.16.0 (current one) or you can download a .whl file which suits your python,processor configuration run dt .whl file and your good to go